# Why does Microsoft Test Manager expect test DLL's under a bin/debug folders structure?

Tags: tfsbuild, microsoft-test-manager

When I attempt to run automated tests via Microsoft Test Manager, I get the error

> "Cannot find the test" .... "with storage '..\bin\debug\mytest.dll".

Why is it looking in there?

By build agent working directory is C:\MyBuildOutput, so when a build is run, the DLL's are output to C:\MyBuildOutput\Binaries.

So why does Microsoft Test Manager expect to find the DLL's under C:\MyBuildOutput\bin\debug ?

I haven't told Microsoft Test Manager to look there, and in fact my build definition build process parameters build my solution in Release mode!

I can get it to work by getting a script to create a bin and debug folder and copying the DLL's in there - but that's just plain inconvenient!!

I think it also expects the bin and debug folder even when I specify a custom build directory using the Microsoft Test Manager command-line utility (tcm.exe).

I'm grateful to hear any explanations, solutions, ideas or thoughts!

Thanks

EDIT: As per solution below, MS Test Manager DOES NOT EXPECT test DLL's under a bin/debug folder (although the error message does almost imply it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

As per [the forum thread here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/vsmantest/thread/beada824-1756-43e3-8719-feaa166cbfd4?prof=required), the reason I was getting this message was nothing to do with the DLL. My ordered test list should have been placed at the project level - not contained within any folders. So, actually Microsoft Test Manager was looking for the ordered test list within the same folder as my test DLL, when in fact it was under a child folder.

When I moved the ordered test list to the same folder as the test DLL, the tests executed successfully.